# Why does OnException always catch NullReferenceException

Tags: asp.net-web-api

This is a strange one. In my WebAPI I've implemented an ExceptionFilterAttribute in order to handle exceptions thrown from my controllers:

```
public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        string actionName = actionExecutedContext.ActionContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName + "/" + actionExecutedContext.ActionContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName;

        if (actionExecutedContext.Exception is UnauthorizedAccessException)
        {
        }
        else if (actionExecutedContext.Exception is BadRequestException)
        {
        }
        else
        {
        }

    }
```

However when this is run the actionExecutedContext.Exception is always a NullReferenceException. Even if I test this and manually an UnauthorizedAccessException from my controller the same thing happens.

Anyone know why my exception is being replaced? How do I get to my original exception?

Comment: If I had to guess, what about the assignment to `actionName` itself causing a NRE? There's a lot of stuff you are digging into, are you sure it's all there?

Comment: If you [turn on first-chance exceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d14azbfh.aspx) does it break somewhere in your code where the `NullReferenceException` is initially thrown?

Comment: Dean, spot on. Once I turned that on I could see that we have a another filter that takes in the HttpResponseMessage and uses it without checking if it's null, however because the controller throws an exception there is no response message. If you want to write an answer then I'll accept it.